# Zend_Tool problem

Tags: zend-studio, zend-server, zend-tool

This is the third time I'm installing zend studio and zend server now these two are installed succesfully (after half a day). But when I'm trying to create a new project I always get this zf error...

`
    ***************************** ZF ERROR ********************************
    In order to run the zf command, you need to ensure that Zend Framework
    is inside your include_path.  There are a variety of ways that you can
    ensure that this zf command line tool knows where the Zend Framework
    library is on your system, but not all of them can be described here.

```
The easiest way to get the zf command running is to give it the include 
path via an environment variable ZEND_TOOL_INCLUDE_PATH or 
ZEND_TOOL_INCLUDE_PATH_PREPEND with the proper include path to use,
then run the command "zf --setup".  This command is designed to create
a storage location for your user, as well as create the zf.ini file
that the zf command will consult in order to run properly on your
system.  

Example you would run:

$ ZEND_TOOL_INCLUDE_PATH=/path/to/library zf --setup

Your are encourged to read more in the link that follows.
Zend_Tool & CLI Setup Information
(available via the command line "zf --info")
   * Home directory found in environment variable HOMEPATH with value \Users\admin
   * Storage directory assumed in home directory at location \Users\admin/.zf/
   * Storage directory does not exist at \Users\admin/.zf/
   * Config file assumed in home directory at location \Users\admin/.zf.ini
   * Config file does not exist at \Users\admin/.zf.ini

To change the setup of this tool, run: "zf --setup"
```

ok (took 0:04.038)
`

I've already set the ZF_INCLUDE_PATH via command line with a new zend-framework library.

I never had a clean install with anything related to zend.

Could someone help me with this?

Thanks

Comment: Apparently I can't even setup a proper virtualhost, when I uncomment the Include conf/extra/httpd-vhosts.conf part in httpd.conf I get an error when I restart my apache server."The requested operation failed" I always have this error and I never know how to get around it, with previous setups I needed to do a whole lot of stuf before I can start a new project.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I presume from the paths you are working on a windows machine. Zend Studio uses the zend tool (zf.bat in windows) to create a project. To make it work you must have properly installed the zend tool, i.e. you must be able to open a console (WINDOWS+R, type cmd, type enter) and successfully run the zf command.

In your case probably is a path issue, that you can resolve following the instructions here: http://framework.zend.com/manual/en/zend.tool.framework.clitool.html#zend.tool.framework.clitool.setup-windows

In particular:

> The most common setup in the Windows Win32 environment, is to copy the zf.bat and zf.php into the same directory as your PHP binary. This can generally be found in one of the following places:

```
C:\PHP
C:\Program Files\ZendServer\bin\
C:\WAMP\PHP\bin
```

> You should be able to run php.exe on the command line. If you are not able to, first check the documentation that came with your PHP distribution, or ensure that the path to php.exe is in your Windows PATH environment variable.
>
> The next order of business is to ensure that Zend Framework library is set up correctly inside of the system PHP include_path. To find out where your include_path is located, you can type php -i and look for the include_path variable, or more succinctly execute php -i | grep include_path if you have Cygwin setup with grep available. Once you have found where your include_path is located (this will generally be something like C:\PHP\pear, C:\PHP\share, C:\Program%20Files\ZendServer\share or similar), ensure that the contents of the library/ directory are put inside your include_path specified directory.

Answer (score 0):

If you are running on Ubuntu or Debian--or maybe Linux in general--it now seems you must create the environment variable **ZEND_TOOL_INCLUDE_PATH**. Having zend framework in your **include_path** (or copying zend framework to you existing **include_path**) no longer seems to work.

To manually install the latest version zend framework on Ubuntu/Debian, this is what I did after downloading ZF and extracting it to ~/temp

```
sudo cp -R ~/temp/ZendFramework-1.11.11/library/Zend /usr/share/php
sudo cp -R ~/temp/ZendFramework-1.11.11/extras/library/ZendX /usr/share/php
sudo cp ~/temp/ZendFramework-1.11.11/bin/zf.sh /usr/bin
sudo cp ~/temp/ZendFramework-1.11.11/bin/zf.php /usr/bin
```

Next edit /etc/environment, if you want other programs, like Netbeans, to be able to invoke zf.sh. Edit ~/.pam_environment, if you want only the current user to execute zf.sh. Add this line:

```
ZEND_TOOL_INCLUDE_PATH=/usr/share/php
```

You may need to log out and log back in after doing this.