# Zend framework 2.0.6 CLI tool not working

Tags: php, wamp, zend-framework2

Been scratching my head for almost 2 days.
I've downloaded **"Zend Framework 2.0.6 Minimal"**.
I'm trying to set it to work using **"Wamp Server 2.2E"**.

Since I didn't find a CLI tool inside the ZendFramework **bin** folder I've downloaded the **zf.bat** & **zf.php** from [Here](http://framework.zend.com/svn/framework/standard/trunk/bin/)
I've placed them inside my wamp PHP folder (since I've already have a path for it on windows)

I've also mapped the library path in my **php.ini** file, located on wamp so it'll be as such: `D:\wamp\bin\php\ZendFramework\library`

Now when I open Windows PowerShell and type zf I get the following error:

```
***************************** ZF ERROR ********************************
In order to run the zf command, you need to ensure that Zend Framework
is inside your include_path.  There are a variety of ways that you can
ensure that this zf command line tool knows where the Zend Framework
library is on your system, but not all of them can be described here.

The easiest way to get the zf command running is to give it the include
path via an environment variable ZEND_TOOL_INCLUDE_PATH or
ZEND_TOOL_INCLUDE_PATH_PREPEND with the proper include path to use,
then run the command "zf --setup".  This command is designed to create
a storage location for your user, as well as create the zf.ini file
that the zf command will consult in order to run properly on your
system.

Example you would run:

$ ZEND_TOOL_INCLUDE_PATH=/path/to/library zf --setup

Your are encourged to read more in the link that follows.
Zend_Tool & CLI Setup Information
(available via the command line "zf --info")
   * Home directory found in environment variable HOMEPATH with value \Users\Shahar Galukman
   * Storage directory assumed in home directory at location \Users\Shahar Galukman/.zf/
   * Storage directory does not exist at \Users\Shahar Galukman/.zf/
   * Config file assumed in home directory at location \Users\Shahar Galukman/.zf.ini
   * Config file does not exist at \Users\Shahar Galukman/.zf.ini

To change the setup of this tool, run: "zf --setup"
```

So even though all the paths seems to be in order I'm still recieving this error.

I've used [Zend guide](http://framework.zend.com/manual/1.12/en/zend.tool.framework.clitool.html) on installing the CLI

And also found a [question here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6507844/zend-tool-problem) which the answer didn't helped me

What else should I do?
Is Zend framework 2.0.6 can even use a CLI?
Is there another solution to manage and work comfortably with Zend framework?

Thanks for any help given,
Shahar

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Zend Framework 2 does not have a CLI-Tool like Zend Framework 1 had. It is still in development and may or may not be released anytime soon. The ZF1 tool will not work for ZF2! That's why it's not included after all ;)

Comment: How can we find this development tool?